# Index out of bounds error ArrayList

Tags: java

```
    for (int i = 0; i < totalArray.size(); i++){

        studentNumber.add(Long.parseLong(totalArray.get(i * 3)))
        lastName.add(totalArray.get((i * 3) + 1));
        firstName.add(totalArray.get((i * 3) + 2));
```

I'm not sure what is going on here. I've getting an index out of bounds error on this code. totalArray.size() is 42 however I'm getting the error at index 42 with the second line (parseLong).

Comment: The max index is size - 1 since index starts from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cricket_007 points out, on the 14th iteration of your for statement, i is 14 and your second line attempts to access element 42 of your index (where the last element of your array is accessed as element 41 because it's 0 indexed).

To stop the for statement at the proper place, merely do the inverse operations which you do on your last line of code.

```
i < (totalArray.size()-2)/3
```

(which was pointed out by Benjamin Lowry).

Answer (score 0):

You're multiplying your `i` by 3 in your `studentNumber.add(Long.parseLong(totalArray.get(i * 3)))` line, so when i >= 14, it goes out of bounds.

Try setting it to `studentNumber.add(Long.parseLong(totalArray.get(i)))` and run it. You probably wanted to place your `* 3` outside the first parenthesis, but I can't deduct your logic.

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is 14, you are getting the index 42 with `i * 3`. Which is out of bounds for a list of size 42.

Answer (score 0):

Your third line triples the number. This means that if i was 30 (which is possible with your current set up), then when tripled, would equal 90, which is obviously above your max size.

You need to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < (totalArray.size() - 2) / 3 ; i++)
```

In order for your code to work. Otherwise all three of your lines will exceed the max at some point.